# db.insert add values random?

Tags: android, sqlite

The question is simple and to put it in just one line : " The insert() function of SQLiteDatabase for Android tries to add the values in a random way ".

Meaning :

```
// Database creation sql statement
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_NAME 
        +"( "
        + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_LATITUDE + "integer,"
        + COLUMN_LONGTITUDE + "integer,"
        + COLUMN_TITLE + "text,"
        + COLUMN_TEXT + " text not null"
        + ");";
```

And when i put the values and try to insert them :

```
values.put(COLUMN_ID, marker.getId() );
values.put(COLUMN_LATITUDE, marker.getLatitude()  ); // lat
values.put(COLUMN_LONGTITUDE, marker.getLongtitude() ); // long     
values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, marker.getTitle()  ); // Title     
values.put(COLUMN_TEXT, marker.getText() ); // Text     

// Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

but the error i got is : 
 E/Database(2542): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: **table Items has no column named longtitude:** , while compiling: INSERT INTO items(longtitude, text,                                         title, latitude, _id) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);

so i guess is tries to put the longtitude where the Id is and that causes the Error.

Is my assumption right? What do i need to change?

Comment: Make sure that your table exists before running the insert. You can do this by setting a breakpoint at the insert, then using adb to connect to your sqlite db and running a .tables command

Comment: good point. i'll check is asap

Comment: You are right Chuck. So how i will make it clean that Create will be before start to Insert?

Comment: If you mean, how do you recreate the table, either restart the emulator/uninstall the app, or run some code in onUpgrade() if you are upgrading the db and now have a different table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your create Table statement, you're missing some spaces before the types (integer,text), here's the correct version:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
    + TABLE_NAME 
    +"( "
    + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + COLUMN_LATITUDE + " integer,"
    + COLUMN_LONGTITUDE + " integer,"
    + COLUMN_TITLE + " text,"
    + COLUMN_TEXT + " text not null"
    + ");";
```

Before you didn't create a column named "longitude". Instead "longitudeinteger" was created

Comment: yes you are right. i forgot a space. As Chuck Norris wrote on his comments when i used adb and checked my tables schema i saw the mistake.